# How can I pass parameters from a npm script to another?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am trying to pass the parameters from a npm script to another (that is called by the first one), but I absolutely can't figure out how to do it.

Here is the case, I have the following `scripts` section in my `package.json` :

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "one": "npm run two && npm run three",
    "two": "gulp build",
    "three": "another random command"
  }
}
```

I'm running script `one` like this : `npm run one -- --arg=value`. But I want to dynamically pass down `arg` to the script `two`.

To sum up, what I want is :

1. I type `npm run one -- --arg=value`
2. It runs `npm run two -- --arg=value && npm run three`
3. Which results in running `gulp build --arg=value`, followed by the other random command

Does anybody have an idea ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you simply use `$1` to pass your argument?

Comment: No, "$1" is not interpreted

Answer (score 0):

All three methods below work with `npm run one -- --arg=value`.

### 1. Using [pre & post scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts)

You can run the second script directly and define the third one as a [post script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts).

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "one": "npm run two --",
    "postone": "npm run three",
    "two": "gulp build",
    "three": "another random command"
  }
```

### 2. Using [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)

Pass argument placeholders to individual scripts.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "one": "run-s 'two -- {@}' three --",
    "postone": "npm run three",
    "two": "gulp build",
    "three": "another random command"
  }
```

### 3. Using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Change the first script to run everything with concurrently, instructing that the second script should get pass through arguments.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "one": "concurrently -P 'npm run two -- {@} && npm run three' --",
    "two": "gulp build",
    "three": "another random command"
  }
}
```

Since we are passing only one command to concurrently, there is no concurrency.